# "Expression must evaluate to a node-set" when trying to select a HTML node

Tags: vb.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get a specific part of HTML file using HtmlAgilityPack.

Input HTML file (simplified and cleaned up):

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        <div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div>
        </div>
        Line 1
        Line 2 - Text here
        Line 3
        <div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code:

```
Dim getPage As HtmlDocument = webGet.Load(Uri)
Dim AllTextLines As HtmlNodeCollection = getPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/section[2]/text()")
Dim SecondTextLine As HtmlNodeCollection = getPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html[1]/body[1]/section[2]/#text[2]")
```

Setting the value of `SecondTextLine` fails with this error:

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set

What I want to get is:

1. Only the line that includes "Line 2 - Text here"
2. All text within a section without child elements (`<div>` in my case) but as one node, one string containing all the text.

How can I do this?

EDIT:
I have added XPath tag again, as returned error comes directly from `System.Xml.XPath.XPathException`, not from the HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: It follows a basic xml schema, so xml serialization might be worth looking into

Comment: Can you clarify? In Item **1.** what's the logic which would result in only the line including 2 and not 1 or 3? In item **2.** your section has two child  `<div>` elements so why are you taking any text from that section? It seems to contradict `All text within a section without child elements`.

Comment: @djv Answering your questions. ***1***. I download page every day and content of the second line is critical to judge on further actions to be taken / page content. As mentioned, input HMTL was simplified, but structure was preserved. ***2***. This is the structure of digested page, I have no influence on this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `/html[1]/body[1]/section[2]/#text[2]` is not a valid XPath expression. Lousy error message, but you certainly wouldn't expect it to select anything.

If you want the second text node, that would be `/html[1]/body[1]/section[2]/text()[2]`. But if you want the text "Line 2 - text here" then you're not selecting a node, you're selecting a string within a node, so `SelectNodes()` is the wrong method to be calling. You appear to be using an XPath 1.0 processor, so doing the string manipulation within the XPath expression itself is going to be very difficult, it's usually simplest to return whole nodes to the host language and do the string manipulation there. Alternatively switch to an XPath 2.0 processor and then you can use functions like tokenize() to split the text on newline boundaries.